# How to interpret indexof expression and functions in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to understand the indexof expression(function) of Azure Data Factory.

Example

This example finds the starting index value for the "world" substring in the "hello world" string:

```
indexOf('hello world', 'world')
And returns this result: 6
```

I'm confused by what is meant by the 'index value' and how the example arrived at the result 6.

Also, using the above example, can someone let me know what would be the answer for the following expression?

```
@if(greater(indexof(string(pipeline().parameters.Config),'FilenameMask'),0),pipeline().parameters.Config.FilenameMask,'')
```

indexof

```
{"FilenameMask":"accounts*."}
```

'Config' represents a field in sql database

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#indexof):

> Return the starting position or index value for a substring. This function is not case-sensitive, and indexes start with the number 0.

```
hello world
01234567890
      ^
      +--- "world" found starting at position 6
```

Regarding the 2nd part of your question.  Here's the expression re-written for a bit of clarity:

```
@if( greater(indexof(string(pipeline().parameters.Config),'FilenameMask'),0)
    ,pipeline().parameters.Config.FilenameMask
    ,'')
```

which can be read as follows:

```
if the index of the string "FilenameMask" within x is greater than 0 then
    return x.Filenamemask
else
    return an empty string
```

where x is pipeline().parameters.Config, which is the value of your "Config" column from the database table.  It will hold values such as

`{"sparkConfig":{"header":"true"},"FilenameMask":"cashsales*."}`

and

`{"FilenameMask":"accounts*."}`

The ADF expression can also be read as follows:

```
if the JSON in the Config column contains a "FilenameMask" key then
    return the value of the FilenameMask key
else
    return an empty string
```

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for that. That clears up the first part of my question, thanks. Any ideas on the second part of my question?

Comment: updated the answer to address the 2nd part of your question

Comment: I need to review your answer before I can say it how much it helped, but I just wanted to say thanks for taking time to respond. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Bill, so I'm trying to decipher your explanation. 
So if "FilenameMask is {"FilenameMask":"accounts*."} what is the result you would expect to see? My guess 'accounts', correct?

Comment: Hi @Bill, could you help how to interpre the following ADF expression  ```@if(empty(variables('FilenameMask')),
concat('*.',pipeline().parameters.FileFormat),
concat(variables('FilenameMask'),toLower(pipeline().parameters.FileFormat)))```

Comment: My main problem is with @if (empty)

Comment: per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#if), `if(<expression>, <valueIfTrue>, <valueIfFalse>)`
So if the "Filenamemask" variable is empty, it'll take the `concat('*.'...` path.  Otherwise it'll use `concat(variables('Filenamemask'...)`

Comment: Regarding your earlier question, if `pipeline().parameters.Config` holds the value `{"FilenameMask":"accounts*."} `, then `pipeline().parameters.Config.FilenameMask` evaluates to "accounts*."

Comment: tbh on both your responses I agree (and I understand), but when I put the value {"FilenameMask":"accounts*."} the copy activty ```@if(empty(variables('FilenameMask')),
concat('*.',pipeline().parameters.FileFormat),
concat(variables('FilenameMask'),toLower(pipeline().parameters.FileFormat)))``` doesn't pulll the data from source ... I don't understand

Comment: I still can't seem to grasp ```@if(greater(indexof(string(pipeline().parameters.Config),'FilenameMask'),0),pipeline().parameters.Config.FilenameMask,'')```
Even though you provided a great explanation ...

Comment: Ok, @Bill I think I have figured out ```@if(greater(indexof(string(pipeline().parameters.Config),'FilenameMask'),0),pipeline().parameters.Config.FilenameMask,'')```
Can you help decipher the following expression please ```@if(equals(variables('RecursiveFlag'),'1'), 1, 0)``` I'm happy to reopen another question on this issue if you prefer?

Comment: Hey @Patterson, if you haven't already, I can strongly recommend spending some time with the excellent article in the official docs about expression and functions in Azure Data Factory.  You can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions).  It really helped my on my ADF journey and is bookmarked in my browser!